# Could President Obama sue "The Right" for Defamation?

Tags: united-states, law, president

A lot of debunked claims have been spread about President Obama throughout his presidency; including, but not limited, to:

1. [Obama is a Muslim](http://www.snopes.com/politics/obama/muslim.asp).
2. [Obama was not born in this country](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/rss_viewer/birth-certificate-long-form.pdf).
3. [Obama is a communist/socialist/monarchist/etc.](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/12/04/sarah-palin-obama-socialist_n_2237163.html)..

While the source of these statements is unclear (defined here as "The Right" for brevity), if the president were to theoretically identify the perpetrator(s) and take them to court, would he have a case--or is all fair in love and politics? An argument could be made that such a tactic might benefit towards the goal of "refocusing" the people away from the tabloid "issues" that seem to dominate a lot of political discussions today.

Comment: The 'socialist' part isn't even untrue. In the context of U.S. economic policy, Obama is very clearly on the socialist side, as is all of the far-left of the Democratic party. This might not be accurate in the context of Western/Central European economic policy, but it certainly is within the context of U.S. economic policy. At any rate, the answer is no. As the answers explain, it's almost impossible for a politician to sue for slander. Even in the case of Harry Reid making blatently false statements about Romney's taxes _which even he knew to be false_, it was not litigated.

Comment: @reirab It might to the left of something or other but it's still not true in every meaningful definition of the word “socialist”. There is a whole range of policies and systems that could be construed as being to the left of the Republican party or the mainstream of American politics but calling all that “socialism” redefines the word beyond recognition or usefulness.

Comment: I think reirab's point--even if unintentionally made--is that a lot of political slander is really impossible to peg as actual slander.

Comment: @Relaxed, Surely you would agree that Obama and the Democratic party advocates for increased levels of socialism within the U.S. than the average American advocates for? Almost no modern economy is either 100% socialist or 100% capitalist, but rather at some point on a continuum between the two. Within the portion of that continuum occupied by U.S. politics, Obama is certainly on the socialist side. That's not really even debatable under almost any definition of socialism. That aside, I was agreeing with your answer, which explains the situation well.

Comment: @reirab you are confusing 'social programs' with 'socialism'. Obama is also hardly 'far left'.

Comment: @reirab I think I do see your point and probably mostly agree with it but I still object to the terminology. I don't see the point in calling any vaguely left-wing policy “socialism”.

Comment: @Relaxed By definition, anything that involves the state owning something for the purpose of producing a good or service is socialism. So, yeah, that does encompass many/most 'left-wing' economic policies. While socialism is commonly associated with Communism (due to an extreme degree of socialism being included in Communism,) a policy doesn't have to be Communist to be socialist. DA, No, I'm not.

Comment: @reirab what "left-wing economic policies" do you equate as being socialist?

Comment: @DA I don't want to get into a long discussion in the comments, so this will be my last comment on the matter. Here's an example, though: nationalizing one of the nation's largest auto manufacturers. Even if the intent was to eventually sell it, it's pretty hard to argue that having the government own a majority stake in a multi-billion-dollar company (not to mention ignoring the claims of more senior debt holders) is not socialism. The gov't building a network of high-speed rail lines would also be socialism. Even things that most agree on like gov't-owned utilities are examples of socialism.

Comment: @reirab feel free to hit me up in chat. I think it's an interesting topic. (FYI, he didn't nationalize the auto manufacturer. It's back in private hands). As for public transit, I think many would agree that's really stretching the term 'socialism'.

Comment: @reirab Even with this watered down notion of socialism, which major Obama policy fits the definition? His signature reform, Obamacare, bends over backwards to make sure the role of the state is limited to providing financial incentives and a regulatory framework rather than directly owning or operating any major elements of the healthcare system. It's quite typical of third way thinking, trying to incorporate market mechanisms everywhere possible and trying to soften some of the effects of capitalism rather than looking for alternatives, however modest in scope.

Comment: ...And this is one of the reasons you could absolutely not convince a US court that "socialism" is a specific statement of fact about policies.

Comment: It is next to impossible for the politician to successfully sue for defamation in the US for claims related to his political actions, and this is a good thing. Politics should be done in the court of public opinion, not in the court of law. If you need the police to tell you right from wrong - you are not doing it right. The US law mostly assumes US population is grown up enough to know right from wrong without the policeman present.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is a question about law, which belongs to https://law.stackexchange.com. Just because the plaintiff is a politician doesn't mean the question is political. Unfortunately the question is too old for a migration.

Comment: Surely, under the definitions of 'socialist' given here then every single US politician is a socialist.  Anyone who is in favour of any programme which could be seen as 'socialist' is a 'socialist' by the transitive property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few problems with this idea:

- Free speech protection is very extensive in the US, especially for the press (and many of these rumors have been spread by media outlets). Winning a defamation case is more difficult there than in many European countries for example. It is virtually impossible for public officials (see comments).
- You can only sue specific people or other legal entities (or if you can sue or press charges against an unnamed person, this person must first be identified before any trial). So you can go after a specific claim and the person who made it but not sue “the right” for spreading a rumor.
- What's the point? Defamation or libel cases have a large tactical element to them. You can sometimes prevent some information from being published or get some monetary compensation and some people try to sue about things they know to be true simply to make a point but once a claim is out there, you can't undo it or prevent those who are so inclined to believe it. There is very little to gain for anybody (and huge potential for negative press: “Obama-the-tyrant is trying to silence the media”) in trying to resolve this in front of the courts.

Incidentally, I would speculate that any attempt to go in this direction would be litigated for years, adding to the negative publicity and possibly finally making its way to the Supreme Court, which could really go both ways.

Comment: For public officials, it's even _harder_ to win a libel case: they have to prove that not only is a statement false, but that the speaker actually _knew_ it was false or probably false (the latter is called "reckless disregard for the truth", but goes further than simply being negligent about fact-checking). If you can't prove they don't honestly believe what they're saying, you can't win a libel claim as a public official. It's really pretty much impossible to win such a case.

Comment: Also, see the [Streisand Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect), where trying to suppress something just makes it that much more talked-about.

Comment: "has not seemed particularly favorable to Obama in the last few years" - SRSLY? Upholding Obamacare based on a fig list wording isn't favorable?

Comment: @DVK It's possible the legal case for the constitutionality of the law was not very strong, I haven't looked into the details and I am not a specialist. But from where I sit, far away from the US and with no particular stake in what's going on there, all the emotion around this particular law or Obama's actions in general is difficult to comprehend. So even though the court ultimately upheld the law, nullifying bits and pieces of it looks quite hostile to me.

Comment: @DVK I edited this sentence, maybe it's better now?

Comment: @Relaxed - much better yes :)

Comment: @Relaxed - the linchpin of the law was upheld, because individual mandate was ruled to be a tax and thus within constitutional jurisdiction of Congress to enact. Except the individual mandate architect recently admitted "So the bill 'was written in a tortured way to make sure [the Congressional Budget Office] did not score the mandate as taxes'. In other words, if it was honestly stated that it was a tax when writing the law (which was the position Obama took infront of SCOTUS) the bill would NEVER have passed Congress

Comment: Without individual mandate, the law is basically dead in the water since insurance companies would go out of business.

Comment: "you can sue or press charges against an unnamed person, this person must first be identified before any trial": this isn't entirely true; civil trials can include so-called "John Doe" defendants.  I am not certain of the rules governing this, but it can indeed happen (for example, in civil rights suits against the government). The idea is that the identity of the John Doe defendant may be revealed by evidence uncovered during the course of the trial.

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's what this phrase attempts to describe (or at least my understanding of it). You can sue a fictitious defendant in the hope that the evidence would reveal their identity during the course of the procedure but would it come to an actual trial without that? The larger point of course is that a defendant must at least in principle be an individual person or organisation that could be identified, at least in principle.

Answer (score 10):

Leaving aside Obama's personal issues for the moment, historical precedent says that you mostly can't.

Talking *&it about your political opponents is as old as American democracy itself. Or, at least, as old as having 2 competing parties - see the infamous first 2 party elections of 1800:

- **Thomas Jefferson**'s side critiqued President John Adams by stating

  > "a hideous hermaphroditical character, which has neither the force and firmness of a man, nor the gentleness and sensibility of a woman."
- **Adams' side** retorted with high-brow:

  > "a mean-spirited, low-lived fellow, the son of a half-breed Indian squaw, sired by a Virginia mulatto father."

More wonderful accusations of the sort familiar to 2000s ("infidel", "fool", "no god", etc) can be found [**in this article**](http://reason.com/blog/2010/10/29/sources-for-attack-ads-circa-1) - there were just too many pearls (with citations) to quote here, so make sure to read them all.

Another good article with examples from other elections **[is here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2008/10/12/AR2008101201966.html)**

---

For some good historical perspective on **legal** issues involved: [http://www.amazon.com/Protecting-Best-Men-Interpretive-History/dp/0807842907](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0807842907)

Comment: Politics are a lot more fun when there's nothing important at stake. That's why I like small government.

Comment: Wasn't that part of the rational behind the Alien and Sedition Act of 1798? I can see why President Adams would sign it into law.

Answer (score 8):

Relaxed answered well for the general case, but there's a separate issue with your third point: In the US, you *cannot* successfully sue for libel over an opinion based on disclosed facts; nor can you sue for hyperbole; nor can you sue for an opinion that's just a pure opinion (and doesn't imply any statements of fact). Libel is restricted to saying a false statement of fact about someone, or implying knowledge of some fact that's actually false. To say that calling Obama a socialist/Marxist/communist/whatever-ist is libel, he'd first have to argue that you're implying that you know some fact (which can be objectively proved or disproved) that you're not mentioning; if a court finds that you're just expressing an opinion of his policies, he's out of luck in the suit.

Comment: Yeah, but with the birther stuff you can more strongly make the case that the people making the claims knew or should have known it was false.  You can also make a case about the Muslim stuff, although not quite as strong as the birther claims.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This answer is just about the third part: socialism/communism/etc. However, "should have known" isn't enough for a public official: To sustain a libel suit, they need to prove that the defendant _actually_ knew their statements were false, or thought that they were probably false. If the defendant just thought "sounds plausible" and didn't bother to check, even if the fact-checking would be fairly simple, there's no libel. Mere negligence is explicitly not enough to qualify as "reckless disregard for the truth" (and thus as "actual malice")

Comment: OK, but at least for some Birchers, I think you could plausibly argue that there was reckless disregard for the truth.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Short of a notarized statement from the Birther saying "I know Obama was born in the US, but..", you'd be fighting an incredibly difficult battle. On the off chance you happened to win the trial, you'd lose again on appeal.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - (competent legal representation): "Your Honor, while it may seem like almost anyone should have known these statements were false or defamatory, my client is exceptionally ignorant, and did not."  Proving malice combined with the absence of plain stupidity as a factor would be fairly impossible to prove, short of having documentation where the defendant basically saying "yeah, I know it's false."  That's a tough bar to reach.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I think people do get successfully prosecuted for defamation on the grounds of reckless disregard for the truth as opposed to knowingly telling a falsehood.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - when it's public officials, criticism and "reporting what I heard," generally, no, they don't get successfully sued unless one can show intentional malice, in the USA. One can claim (A) political free speech, (B) using enough weasel wording that they are merely reporting on claims or "asking the question" as opposed to reporting false statements as fact, or (C) if they are intentionally disparaging, claim it's parody.  If you can find evidence otherwise, I'd be happy to check it out, but if that were not the case, Fox News would already be out of business.

Comment: A case in point: Penn and Teller's cable TV show *Bullsh!t* was titled specifically because that epithet is regarded as an opinion and not a representation of fact. If you say that some con artist's flim-flam is false, you are open to a defamation suit; but calling it by the term that Penn uses insulates you entirely.